# How to...unevenly blow up a shape?

Tags: inkscape

This should be pretty simple (famous last words).  I want to make a custom wax seal for our wedding invitations.  We're both DND nerds, and so we'd like to start with an SVG of a D20, and replace the 20 with our last initial. Starting with something like this:

[image]

We will likely choose to remove the numbers on the outside, to make the design cleaner.  My concern is that as it is, the initial will look too small if I have it as the same size as the 20 is in this image.

What I'd like to do is some kind of distortion on it in Inkscape or similar, as if you were looking at it through a fisheye lens.  I want the center triangle to grow, while the overall size of the image does not.  So the edges are shrunk and the middle is expanded.  I'm not really sure how to go about this.  Any ideas?

Comment: See also [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3076/fisheye-effect-in-inkscape)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to keep the lines straight or go for a fish-eye lens look?

Photoshop's Liquify > Bloat Tool can do this in 5 seconds…

[image]

That would require you changed the content first in vector, then bloat a rastered image.

Comment: That looks great!  I was thinking that with what I wanted to do, it wouldn't be feasible to do straight lines, but looking at what you have there, I think I could pretty easily just eyeball it by connecting straight lines with each of the vertices.  I'm not sure, but with that, it looks like I could try both and see how it looks.

Also, bloat was apparently the vocabulary word I needed.  Looks like an analogous tool exists in Illustrator, and maybe even Inkscape (although it's not clear how well that works).  Thanks for such a quick answer!

Comment: Most welcome :) I don't actually use vector-based apps myself, I live in Photoshop, normally working on 'actual' photos - but I'm glad I could help.